# shared preference & storage permission

Tags: permissions, android-sharedpreferences

I have some data saved to my Shared Preferences  i am able to access it until i am not changing storage permission explicitly in application permission in marshmallow(Does not matter in first time this is allowed or not).

CASE 1: when i change storage permission to allow for any task at run time this is working fine,NO issue.

Case 2: again i try to read from shared preference but this time i have denied storage permission explicitly in application permission, its crashes with a null pointer exception,

kindly confirm storage permission is related to external storage or internal storage as well as shared preference.

log for error :

```
**02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)**
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.SpecialClassMappingForSharedPreference.getData()' on a null object reference
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.Function.compareAndUpdateModelName(Function.java:3549)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.Function.readModelName(Function.java:3665)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.Function.readServiceData(Function.java:2539)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.ReadWriteTask.doInBackground(ReadWriteTask.java:229)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-03 12:59:52.235: E/AndroidRuntime(6970):     ... 4 more
02-03 12:59:52.431: I/com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.Utility(6970): getFileList
02-03 12:59:52.436: I/com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.Utility(6970): getFileList
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.serviceconnection.ServiceConnection has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{940db25 V.E...... R......D 0,0-959,192} that was originally added here
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.ReadWriteTask.onPreExecute(ReadWriteTask.java:199)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at com.necdisplay.IntlWirelessDataApp.common.AsyncTaskForTagDetection.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskForTagDetection.java:205)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-03 12:59:52.961: E/WindowManager(6970):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences are not affected by user app permissions afaik.
Even writing files in app directory don't require permissions, according to docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

I would suspect `SpecialClassMappingForSharedPreference` to cause the issue.

Comment: Please can u review this question and yes I am storing in the app directory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319152/permission-and-path-for-hive-flutter?r=SearchResults