# permission and path for hive flutter

Tags: flutter, path, permissions, storage

I am currently building an application in which I am storing data and doing crud operations with the help of package hive for flutter. So my question is do I need to ask for permissions regarding storing data if yes then which permissions and what should be the ideal path for storing data.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hive, you DON'T need any explicit permission to be added. Plus, it handles caching, making the requests faster.